# Are there ways to solve this algebraic equation by division

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I know I can find solution for These equations using subtraction

$3x+2y=14.....(\text{i})$

$4x+3y=20.....(\text{ii})$

My question is can I divide $(\text{i})$ by $(\text{ii})$ to get values of $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Those are not equations. An equation means that you have a LHS and RHS and an equality sign between them.

Comment: Are you asking this question "randomly" ?

Comment: Try dividing them to see what you get. Remember that the idea of solving such a system using subtraction is to eliminate one of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, eliminatiion by division always works. But you also need to separately consider the case that the eliminated variable $=0.\,$ Let's compare eliminating vs. isolating $x$ then dividing for the system

$$\begin{align} a x + b y = c\\
 d x + e y = f \end{align}$$

Eliminating $x$ we obtain the equation $\ (bd-ae)\, y = cd-af$

Isolating $x$ and dividing we obtain $\  \ a/d = (by-c)/(ey-f)$

Clearing denominators shows that the latter is equivalent to the former, assuming that $d\neq 0$ (which we can assume wlog). Note that $\,ey-f = dx\neq 0\,$ by $\,d,x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations can be written as
$$3x=14-2y $$
$$4x=20-3y $$

$x=0$ yields to a contradiction.
we can assume $x\ne 0$.

by division, we get
$$\frac {3x}{4x}=\frac {14-2y}{20-3y}=\frac {3}{4} $$

thus
$$4 (14-2y)=3 (20-3y )$$
or
$$y=60-56$$
You can finish.

Comment: I am pretty clear now tnx @ salahamam

Comment: @user951215 Such division always works (and is equivalent to standard elimination) - see my answer.

Comment: Tnx sir I am satisfied by your answer @ Bill Dubuque